# How to move and rotate an image

Tags: android

I Have an imageview at the center of the screen. Once the user cliicka a button, i want to move it to "below a text view I have" while rotating it (kinda like a freesbie going from point A to point B) 
How can I achieve that? I know the inageview xnl part, the button listener and all that, but not sure how to
1- move the image to a another position relative to a view (lets say below textview field)
2- rotate the image while moving

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use animation, here is a good link that will get you started with the animation in android. It has example for how to rotate items.

http://www.hascode.com/2010/09/playing-around-with-the-android-animation-framework/#Rotate_Animations

Comment: Thank you for the link. amazing information is there as how to use animation

Comment: One question though, Why use animations Vs onDraw method to rotate using Canvas? I find th eanimations easier but is there a problem with it? thanks

Comment: Using Canvas gives you more flexibility and customization option than animations, especially when multiple animations are involved ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a RotateAnimation to rotate the view and a TranslateAnimation to move it from one place to another.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I wish you provided a link or an example of how to use

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/RotateAnimation.html - for RotateAnimation and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html for TranslateAnimation